# SharedPreference in non-activity-class or RecyclerView adapter class

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have saved sharedpreferences on a settings activity and able to fetch it on load. Also i am able to fetch the same shared preferences in the main activity. However when i am trying to call it on a separate class that i intend to use on a recyclerview adapter so like a prefix in every card view element, i am getting a null error. Below are the challenges:

1. I am facing difficulty in setting up a correct context.
2. I tried creating a getter in the preference class/activity which
   returns null when called from a separate java class.
3. I tried defining a context in the adapter class and using this as follows

---

```
public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
      public Context context;

      ...

sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);    
     userCurrency = sharedPreferences.getString("sPrefix","");
```

**Also tried:**

```
sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
```

I am getting following error when this sharedpreference line  is called.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

Please can you help me how to 
either setup a getter that i can call from a separate class,
or initialize and get values in this separate class directly.

### Main activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button btnm, btnw, btnsep;
Intent intent;
TextView tvRecall;
Third third;
Shared shared;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnm = findViewById(R.id.btnmain);
    btnw = findViewById(R.id.btnwhat);
    btnsep = findViewById(R.id.sepClass);
    tvRecall=findViewById(R.id.txtRecall);

    intent = new Intent(this, Shared.class);

    btnm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    btnw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            String s = sharedPreferences.getString("txt","");
            Log.i("testlog*****","t "+ s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text is " + s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    btnsep.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           third = new Third();
           third.callSharedPreference();
        }
    });

}
```

### Activity to save shared pref

public class Shared extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText textView ;
Button btn;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Context c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shared);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btnName);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            sharedPreferences.edit().putString("txt",textView.getText().toString()).apply();
        }
    });


}

public Shared () {    }

public void getlog () {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
        String s = sharedPreferences.getString("txt","");
        Log.i("testlog*****","t "+ s);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text is " + s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

### Third Class to call the sharedpreference giving null error as above when called

public class Third {

```
Context context;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
String s = sharedPreferences.getString("txt","");


public Third (){}

public void callSharedPreference () {

    Log.i("testlog*****","t "+ s);
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Text is ==== " + s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: What is that `context` Object? Please post the entire code.

Comment: Welcome to SO salman. Have you tried with: `getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);` only one `context`?

Comment: Please add these codes-logs in your question And don't send them as comments. (Use **edit** button) However, check my answer in here too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686439/sharedpreferences-doesnt-work-in-my-model-class/52686487#52686487

Comment: Hi TheWanderer. I have finally figured out to post the code on SO. Just edited my question. Hi Mohsen, Thanks. Just updated to provide a full view of the code

Comment: Thanks Mohsen for the help. I figured it out using your reference. it seems i was passing the wrong context. I am still figuring out how to mark the question answered from your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the class Third  the context is not initialized 
so you should initialize it in the constructor method and pass the value to it when you call the class... 
like this

```
public class Third {
Context context;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
String s = sharedPreferences.getString("txt","");


public Third (Context context){
    this.context=context
}
//...
}
```